# How to set arguments in weblogic via console?

Tags: java, spring-boot, environment-variables, weblogic, weblogic12c

Im trying to set arguments in weblogic ->environment->AdminServer->Server Start -> Arguments
Arguments : -Denvironment=C://path

And then hit save.

From other post and documentation the value should be in JAVA_PROPERTIES, but when I try accessing it like this in my java program:

```
System.getenv("environment")
//Or
System.getProperty("environment")
```

Even printed all properties and the value is not there, is like the weblogic doesn't get updated.

Also from other post in this website it says that I need to reset the weblogic, server, node manager, but I do it and still doesn't work.

Do anybody have steps for correctly setting an argument and use it in java program, or what is the problem?

Also my `JAVA_HOME` and environment variables are set to the java that weblogic use

Weblogic version : 14.1.1
JAVA Version: Open Java 8(Oracle version)

I did a workaround and set it in the `userOverrides.cmd` script and it works, but I need to do it through console arguments.

Comment: are you using node manager to start up it ?

Answer (score 0):

To set `JAVA_PROPERTIES` variable, It has to imported before you start the AdminServer with **startWebLogic.sh** script. You can either edit the **startWebLogic.sh** or Make new script -> Define `JAVA_PROPERTIES` -> Call **startWebLogic.sh** script from that new script.

Then you should be able to use `System.getenv("JAVA_PROPERTIES")` to get value in your java program.